# How to compute Prior Variance

Tags: distributions, bayesian, descriptive-statistics

This might sound a little silly to ask, but I couldn't figure out how an author arrived to the prior variance estimates from this vector:

```
  x <- c(5,3,5,1,2,4)
  y <- c("Lab", "Lib", "Cons", "Other", "None", "Swing")
```

I see how he computed the mean: m = (x/sum(x)) Resulting in the following vector of Prior Means:

> m
>    0.25 0.15 0.25 0.05 0.10 0.20

But I couldn't find out how he got these variances from the date above:

```
Prior Variance: 0.008929, 0.006071, 0.008929, 0.002262, 0.004286, 0.007619
```

Any clue?

Comment: Some context would be nice. What are we looking at? Count data? What's the model? If the priors are based on the observed numbers, what makes them prior?

Comment: If these are votes in an election, than "Swing" usually means change since the previous election rather than actual votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you have are $\frac{m(1-m)}{21}$. Now $\sum_i x_i=20$, so that divisor is one higher than `sum(x)`.

It's a lot like the estimated variance of a proportion in a frequentist variance estimate for a binomial proportion $\hat p(1-\hat p)/n$, but with $n+1$ instead of $n$ on the denominator.

That looks to me more like a posterior variance to go with a particular prior, but I guess it *might* be some kind of prior.

More information about the circumstances would help.